# get data from django form and print in console

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to Django and what I want to do is quite simple, but I am confused:

I want to create a Django form (simple form not ModelForm) and write a function which takes data from this form like username and password(which user types in front-end) and print it in console.

i have tried adding a form to froms.py but am a bit confused regarding the view part

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a view that extends `FormView`:

```
from myapp.forms import YourForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class YourView(FormView):
template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = YourForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
```

And make sure you have a template that will display the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

And when you submit the form, it should print the form's data in your console!